# How to find information from three tables related to each other (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I have created a database **dealer** in `MySQL` which has all the info about 
         a **dealer** like :

```
     dealer id
     dealer name
     dealer email
     dealer phone no
     dealer's primary address
     dealer's billing address
     dealer's contact person
     dealer's contact person's name
     dealer's contact person's email
```

And this information is stored in three tables namely:

```
    dealer
    address
    contact_person
```

The fields and data of tables are given below :

This table **dealer** has **dealer_id** as primary key.

```
    `mysql> select * from dealer;
    +-----------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
    | dealer_id | dealer_name | dealer_email   | dealer_phone_no |
    +-----------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
    |       101 | dell        | dell@gmail.com |      9000000000 |
    |       102 | asus        | asus@gmail.com |      8000000000 |
    |       103 | hp          | hp@gmail.com   |      7000000000 |
    +-----------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
    3 rows in set (0.02 sec)
    `
```

This table **address** has field **dealer_address_id** as primary keyand field **add_dealer_id** as foreign key which references to the table **dealer**'s field **dealer_id**.

```
    `mysql> select * from address;
    +-------------------+---------------+----------------------+-------------+----------------+
    | dealer_address_id | add_dealer_id | add_line1            |  city       |   address_type |
    +-------------------+---------------+----------------------+-------------+----------------+
    |             10001 |           101 | 1, Dell Avenue       | Round Rock  | Primary        |
    |             10002 |           101 | 1, Dell Avenue       | Round Rock  |  Billing       |
    |             10003 |           102 | 1, Asus Computer     | Fremont     |  Primary       |
    |             10004 |           102 | 1, Asus Headquarters | Taipei      | Billing        |
    |             10005 |           103 | HP Inc               | Palo Alto   |  Primary       |
    |             10006 |           103 | HP Inc               | Bristol     |  Billing       |
    +-------------------+---------------+----------------------+-------------+----------------+
    6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
    `
```

And this table **contact_person** has field **contact_person_id** as primary key and field **cp_dealer_id** as foreign key which also references to the tables **dealer**'s field **dealer_id**.

```
    `mysql> select * from contact_person;
    +-------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------------+
    | contact_person_id | cp_dealer_id | con_per_name    | con_per_email          | 
    +-------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------------+
    |              1001 |          101 | Michael S. Dell | michael.dell@gmail.com |       
    |              1002 |          101 | Sam Greenblatt  | sam.dell@gmail.com     |      
    |              1003 |          102 | Jerry Shen      | jerry.asus@gmail.com   |     
    |              1004 |          103 | Dion J. Weisler | dion.hp@gmail.com      |      
    +-------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------------+
    4 rows in set (0.01 sec)`
```

I want to find all the information about a dealer like :

```
    dealer id
     dealer name
     dealer email
     dealer phone no
     dealer's primary address
     dealer's billing address
     dealer's contact person
     dealer's contact person's name
     dealer's contact person's email
```

For example i have queries :

```
    `Find dealer on the basis of dealer id `

    `Find dealer on the basis of dealer name `

    `Find dealer on the basis of dealer email `
```

So please help me how do I do this ?

Comment: Off topic: Is this database related to illegal drugs? Couldn't help mysqlself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a join statement in MySQL.

Here is an example:

```
SELECT Dealer.dealer_id, Dealer.Name, Dealer.Email
FROM Dealer
INNER JOIN Address
ON Dealer.dealer_id=Address.dealer_id;
```

Comment: @ Jay Mason here is what i also did (inner join on three tables) ,

SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  dealer d 
  JOIN contact_person cp 
    ON d.dealer_id = cp.cp_dealer_id 
  JOIN address a 
    ON a.`add_dealer_id` = d.`dealer_id` 
GROUP BY d.`dealer_id`,
  cp.`con_per_name` ;  

This gives me the all information about a dealer.
But what if I want to find specifically by dealer_id or dealer_name.

Comment: And that didn't work because you copied it from the internet and you didn't change the table names? pretty sure "a" "d" and "cp" are not your table names.

Comment: @ Jay Mason it did work because they are used for the tables itself.
as you can see that i have used "a" , "d" and "cp" after the table names.

Comment: @ Jay Mason and for your concern let us assume that i have not used "a" , "d" and "cp"
Than my query would be like

SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  dealer 
  JOIN contact_person
    ON dealer.dealer_id = contact_person.cp_dealer_id 
  JOIN address 
    ON address.`add_dealer_id` = dealer.`dealer_id` 
GROUP BY dealer.`dealer_id`,
  contact_person.`con_per_name` ;

Comment: Right, so you would just add a third table on that. If you use a natural join statement you can grab from all 3. Now I am confused what you're asking?

Comment: I only want to list out all the information about a dealer on the basis of its dealer_id.

Comment: you gave me this solution :------

    SELECT Dealer.dealer_id, Dealer.Name, Dealer.Email
    FROM Dealer
    INNER JOIN Address
    ON Dealer.dealer_id=Address.dealer_id;

--------The third table contact_peroson gives the info about the contact person of a dealer , which you didnot included in your solution .
and in my solution i was Joining all the three tables to get all information about a dealer.